# Error Installing Rails 5.2.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to install Rails 5.2.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 PC using Ruby version -2.5.5 and during the installation I'm facing this error.

```
$ gem install rails -v 5.2.3

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/amani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/ext/nokogiri
/home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190831-23754-eu6kq8.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:574:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:521:in `with_werror'
    from /home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:574:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/amani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:632:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:416:in `<main>'
```

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

```
  /home/amani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/amani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/amani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.4/gem_make.out
```

These are the error messages on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your terminal log and realized that you are using **RVM (Ruby version manager)** as your **ruby manager**. The catch here is that **RVM** seems to be heavyweight as it manages not just your `ruby version` but also your `ruby gems`. A better option for you should be to use **rbenv (Ruby environment)**, which manages just your `ruby version` and **Bundler** which manages **ruby gems**.

This way you will rarely run into conflicts where **RVM** and **Bundler** will be doing the same thing (managing your `ruby gems`), since rails installation depends on **Bundler**.

Here's a simple command built-in that will remove **RVM** and its related directories from your system:

```
rvm implode
```

In order to remove the final trace of rvm, you need to remove the rvm gem, too:

```
gem uninstall rvm
```

If you've made modifications to your `PATH` you might want to pull those, too. Check your `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` files, among other things.

You may also have an `/etc/rvmrc` file, or one in your home directory `~/.rvmrc` that may need to be removed as well.

When you are done with the removal of **RVM** and all of its files and directories, follow this guide [How To Install Ruby on Rails with rbenv on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install a fresh copy of **Ruby on Rails** with **rbenv** on your Ubuntu machine.

If you still run into any issue relating to bundler while using **rbenv**, simply follow the instruction below:

You need to simply install an update for RubyGems Package Manager locally. To do this, run

```
gem update --system
```

If you don't have bundler version 2 installed locally, then run

```
gem install bundler
```

And then finally run

```
bundler update --bundler
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried all these and none worked for me.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Try it out to see if it helps.